# Why field in record is not incrementing

Tags: record, freepascal

I am trying to increment the number field of a simple record in a loop:

```
program Progrecords; 
{$mode objfpc}
Type  
    Progrec = Record  
        pname : string;  
        pnum : integer; 
        end;  
var 
    Progs : Array [1..3] of Progrec; 
    aprog, pp: Progrec; 

function getrec(ppname: string): Progrec; 
begin
    for pp in Progs do begin
        if pp.pname = ppname then
        result := pp ; 
    end; 
end; 

begin 
    aprog.pname := 'abc';   aprog.pnum := 4;    Progs[1] := aprog;
    aprog.pname := 'def';   aprog.pnum := 6;    Progs[2] := aprog;
    for pp in Progs do  writeln('Name: ',pp.pname, '; Num: ', pp.pnum); 

    {increment nums in both recs: }
    pp := getrec('abc');    pp.pnum := pp.pnum + 1; 
    pp := getrec('def');    pp.pnum := pp.pnum + 1; 
    for pp in Progs do  writeln('Name: ',pp.pname, '; Num: ', pp.pnum); 

end.
```

The code compiles and runs all right but the number field is not getting incremented.

The output is:

```
$ fpc rnrecords_so.pas && ./rnrecords_so
Free Pascal Compiler version 3.0.0+dfsg-11+deb9u1 [2017/06/10] for x86_64
Copyright (c) 1993-2015 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Linux for x86-64
Compiling rnrecords_so.pas
Linking rnrecords_so
/usr/bin/ld.bfd: warning: link.res contains output sections; did you forget -T?
31 lines compiled, 0.1 sec
Name: abc; Num: 4
Name: def; Num: 6
Name: ; Num: 0
Name: abc; Num: 4     <<<<<<< NOTE: NUMBERS HAVE NOT BEEN INCREMENTED;
Name: def; Num: 6
Name: ; Num: 0
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Comment: getrec returns a copy of the record. Remember that records are value types. Consider returning the index if the found record. Take care to deal with the case where the record is not found.

Comment: While you're doing `Progs[1|2] := aprog` you're aware that the record is copied to the left hand side. Otherwise `Progs[1]` would end up identical to `Progs[2]`. Why should it be different when you do `pp := getrec('abc');`?

Comment: How can I have a function which increments `pnum` of records?

Comment: `for pp in Progs do pp.pnum := pp.pnum +1; ` also does not work: `Error: Illegal assignment to for-loop variable "pp"`

Comment: `for i := Low(Progs) to High(Progs) do Progs[i].pnum := Progs[i].pnum + 1;`

Comment: Rather than solving this specific problem what you should do is read about the difference between value types and reference types